# Nvidia GPU heating up

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, overheating, paths

I noticed occasionally my GPU was heating up when doing usual tasks (idle + Internet browsing, not video). I select intel-onboard in Nvidia-server but the problem persists.
I used the following command to check gpu frequency and temp and got the following response:

`nvidia-smi`

> NVIDIA-SMI couldn't find libnvidia-ml.so library in your system.
>   Please make sure that the NVIDIA Display Driver is properly installed
>   and present in your system. Please also try adding directory that
>   contains libnvidia-ml.so to your system PATH.

I can get the Nvidia-smi to run using the LD_PRELOAD.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/nvidia-3xx/libnvidia-ml.so nvidia-smi
```

1. Do I have to be worried about drivers functioning properly or is "smi" and "ml" only monitoring. If it is important how do I perminantly set the libnvidia-ml.so path? Note: LD_PRELOAD is a one time solution as running

   `nvidia-smi` again yields "cannot find "libnvid-ml.so".
2. Could this be the reason for the gpu heating up?
3. Where does one report such issues?

Comment: When you say heating up, what do you mean? Is it throttling? Is it indicating high reported temps?  Or does it just seem hot to the touch?  Metal which is 50 degrees C can feel too hot to touch yet GPUs can safely operate usually to at least 70 and often even 85 or 90.

Comment: It fluctuates between 35 C and 60 C when not in use, which is suspicious. I would prefer my machine stay in the low temperature rangers for longevity.  Also if there are any issues with drivers causing the machine to misbehave I would like to know.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *[edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/984245/edit)* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.